# Finding the f(y) in solving volume of solid revolution

Tags: calculus, functions, solid-of-revolution

Good day.

I am trying to solve this question:

"Find the volume of the solid obtained by revolving the indicated region about the given line. The region is bounded by the curves $y=x\sqrt{2-x}$ , $y=6-x$ , and x-axis. It is rotated in the y-axis."

I assigned the $f(x)$ to the $y=x\sqrt{2-x}$ and the $g(x)$ to the $y=6-x$

I learned that when it is rotated in the y-axis, I need to change a function that is terms of x to a function that is in terms with y.

I may hard to find when I tried to change the function, $y=x\sqrt{2-x}$ , to a f(y). While I solved the $g(x)$ from $y=6-x$ to $x=6-y$.

I tried to solve the $y=x\sqrt{2-x}$ first. The first step that I did is squaring the both sides to cancel the square root. And the result is $y^2=2x^2-x^3$. What steps do I need to do to cancel the powers of the x for it to become $f(y)$ ?

Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

From $y=x\sqrt{2-x},$ you get $y^2=x^2(2-x).$ Rearranging terms, $x^3-2x^2+y^2=0.$
Substituting $x=u+\frac{2}{3}$,
$$
0=(u+\frac{2}{3})^3-2(u+\frac{2}{3})^2+y^2=u^3-\frac{4}{3}u+(y^2-\frac{16}{27}).
$$

Then from the formula at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano%27s_formula) for solving "depressed cubics",
$$
u
=\left(-\frac{y^2-\frac{16}{27}}{2}
+\sqrt{\frac{(y^2-\frac{16}{27})^2}{4}-\frac{64}{729}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}
+\left(-\frac{y^2-\frac{16}{27}}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{(y^2-\frac{16}{27})^2}{4}-\frac{64}{729}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}.
$$
Then
$$
x=u+\frac{2}{3}.
$$
The other two solutions can be obtained from multiplying each of the two cube roots by conjugate third roots of unity. Some of these values will be solve $y=x\sqrt{2-x},$ some will solve $y=-x\sqrt{2-x}.$

Comment: Question, (sorry I don't know the Cardano's formula for "depressed cubics" yet, I am currently a 1st year college taking the calculus subject), after I solve for "u", then I will substitute the solved "u" to the x = u + 2/3? Thank you for answering my first question in the thread, this can help me in the future.

Comment: I gave the answer to your question, but to be honest I don't think you are asking the right question. Is it possible that you misunderstood the question somehow? Solving cubics is quite difficult and almost never required in a college class. Is it possible that they want you to rotate around the $x$ axis instead?